# How is the inequality $\|B_n(f)\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I am currently studying the sequence $(B_n(f))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of Bernstein Polynomials $$(B_n(f))(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) {n \choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k},\quad \text{ where }\quad 0\leq x \leq 1,$$ and came across the following inequality in my analysis textbook: $$\|B_n(f)\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \tag{$*$}$$ I already showed that $|B_n(f)| \leq B_n(|f|)$ and $B_n(f) \geq 0$ whenever $f \geq 0$, however, how is the inequality $(*)$ correct? I feel like having shown the other two inequalities I should be able to deduce why $(*)$ is true $($as the author has not provided a proof$)$ but something is not clicking. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Note:** Showing $|B_n(f)| \leq B_n(|f|)$ and $B_n(f) \geq 0$ whenever $f \geq 0$ was an exercise in the textbook $-$ Showing $(*)$ is not as it was mentioned briefly in the book without proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $|B_n(f)(x)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$.

Now,
$$
1=1^n=(x+(1-x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^k(1-x)^{n-k},
$$
by the binomial identity.

Comment: Does that mean $sup |B_n(f)(x)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k}$?

Comment: I'm just confused as to why this helps prove $\|B_n(f)\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \tag{$*$}.$ If you could elaborate more to help me see why this holds using what you said, that would be much appreciated (-:.

Comment: If you add all the lines together, you now have $|B_n(f)(x)|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ for every $x$.

Comment: Okay, then does this imply that: $|B_{n}(f)(x)| \leq sup |B_{n}(f)(x)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon The right-hand side doesn't depend on $x$... so what do you conclude?

Comment: That since the right hand side is not dependent on your choice of $x$, that $||B_{n}(f)||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_{\infty}$?

Comment: @TaylorRendon If you're in doubt about this, it sounds like you need to recall the definition of the supremum.

Comment: So is what I said incorrect?

Comment: @TaylorRendon No.